# Exception while using Apache POI on a JSP

Tags: java, excel, jsp, exception, apache-poi

I'm trying to implement Apache POI to display the data on an Excel file into some inputs on my web page. I'm getting this exception:

```
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:677)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.validateImport(Node.java:628)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.addImport(Node.java:611)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parsePageDirective(Parser.java:352)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:473)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1773)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:135)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

And this the code I have on my .jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream, 
java.io.FileNotFoundException, 
java.io.IOException, 
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell, 
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow,
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet,
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<% 
     HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("excel.xls"));
     HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
     HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
     double Something,Something1,Something2,Something3,Something4;

        Something= row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
        Something1= row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
        Something2= row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
        Something3= row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
        Something4= row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue(); 

 %>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Something: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something1: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something1 %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something2: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something2 %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something3: </td>
            <td>    <input type="text" value="<% Something3 %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something4: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something4 %>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does someone knows where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which server you are using. But if it is Tomcat 7.0.57 or later(Have a look at [this link](https://discuss.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206211847-Upgrade-to-Tomcat-7-0-57-and-8-0-15-or-Later-may-Cause-JSP-Compilation-Error-HTTP-Status-500-Unable-to-compile-class-for-JSP-on-JSP-Page) too), then you need to remove the semicolon (;) at the end of import directives. Try removing that and it should work.

Comment: That solves that problem, but I'm getting other error: 
    An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\work\Catalina\localhost\HelloWorldJSP\org\apache\jsp\helloWorld_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell resolves to a package


And more things like that....

Comment: Kindly create another question for the next problem as it isn't related with this issue. If this resolved the existing issue, then you can accept the answer.