# Exception implementing Apache POI on a JSP

Tags: java, excel, jsp, exception, apache-poi

I'm trying to implement Apache POI on a JSP to read an excel file and take the values of some cells and display it on the inputs I have on my page. But I'm getting this error:

```
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /helloWorld.jsp
HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
13: <body>
14: 
15: <%
16:         HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("excel.xls"));
17:         HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
18:         HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
19:         double Something,Something1,Something2,Something3,Something4;

An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /helloWorld.jsp
HSSFSheet cannot be resolved to a type     
14: 
15: <%
16:         HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("excel.xls"));
17:         HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
18:         HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
19:         double Something,Something1,Something2,Something3,Something4;


An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /helloWorld.jsp
HSSFRow cannot be resolved to a type
15: <%
16:         HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("excel.xls"));
17:         HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
18:         HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
19:         double Something,Something1,Something2,Something3,Something4;



Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

And this the code I have on my .jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<% 
     HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("excel.xls"));
     HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
     HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
     double Something,Something1,Something2,Something3,Something4;

        Something= row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
        Something1= row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
        Something2= row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
        Something3= row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
        Something4= row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue(); 

 %>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Something: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something1: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something1 %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something2: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something2 %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something3: </td>
            <td>    <input type="text" value="<% Something3 %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Something4: </td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<% Something4 %>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I already add the needed jar files.

---

**Edit:**
At a beginning the import was like this:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow"%>
```

But it was throwing this error above the error shown at the beginning:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\work\Catalina\localhost\HelloWorldJSP\org\apache\jsp\helloWorld_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\work\Catalina\localhost\HelloWorldJSP\org\apache\jsp\helloWorld_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\work\Catalina\localhost\HelloWorldJSP\org\apache\jsp\helloWorld_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow resolves to a package
```

Comment: Its not a duplicate from a question I did before, the other question had almost the same problem, but was solved, and the one who solves it told me to open a new question with the new error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to verify that is that `poi.jar` file is available in your exported war file or not ? If it is not there then try to rebuild your war.

if yes the try this

use specifice import statement like this...

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.* ,java.io.*"%>
```

instead of

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
```

follow this [Link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package) OR [Link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962709/only-a-type-can-be-imported-abc-resolves-to-a-package)

because the error stack trace shows the error

```
HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type //won't be able to find class HSSFWorkbook in library.
```

Class cannot be resolved to a type always occurs when a particular class is not
available in your war library.

Comment: at a beginnig it was like that, but it was throwing this error for HSSFWorkbook and the same for the other ones(but instead of HSSFworkbook, says its name): An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\work\Catalina\localhost\HelloWorldJSP\org\apache\jsp\helloWorld_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook resolves to a package

Comment: let me edit the code for you to see what I mean.

Comment: please update your question with your new stacktrace Error.. Thanks.

Comment: Done, its at the bottom.

Comment: If I add a semicolon like one of the links you provided, It throws me the error I showed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471492/exception-while-using-apache-poi-on-a-jsp/38471561#38471561, I imported the jar files through the buildpath and adding external jar files: poi-3.14-20160307.jar and poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: And I also tried the import statement you showed, and its the same.